# How to get total count include model Sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

please tell me how can I get the count of all elements in a nested table?
Why variantCount is not correct? Must be 5, but i get only 1.

I will be very grateful for your help

```
products = await Product.findAll({
        attributes: ['name', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'variant.id'), 'variantCount']],
        include: [{ model: ProductVariant, as: 'variant', attributes: ['title', 'img'] }],
        group: ['product.id', 'variant.id'],
      })
```

OUTPUT: `

```
[
    {
        "name": "nike-metcon-7",
        "variantCount": "1",
        "variant": [
            {
                "title": "Nike Metcon 7 (Grey)",
                "img": "f7b6faf0-0522-4443-83c5-3ceeebc54453.jpg"
            },
            {
                "title": "Nike Metcon 7 (Blue)",
                "img": "e8d105a3-2704-4d08-97d7-7382fdb940b1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "title": "Nike Metcon 7 (White)",
                "img": "66c01ec6-ec09-4dec-be24-5164358440ed.jpg"
            },
            {
                "title": "Nike Metcon 7 (Grey)",
                "img": "b0c72280-e116-479c-a3c2-f323b462a861.jpg"
            },
            {
                "title": "Nike Metcon 7 (Red)",
                "img": "c93a50fe-14a5-4e0f-a5d1-014bc45dc3c9.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try subquerying the exact output which will be concise than pulling count from  a left joined table

```
products = await Product.findAll({
        attributes: ['name', [Sequelize.literal('(select count(variant.id) from ProductVariant where product.variant_id = variant.variant_id)'), 'variantCount']],
        include: [{ model: ProductVariant, as: 'variant', attributes: ['title', 'img'] }],
        group: ['product.id', 'variant.id'],
      })
```

Comment: SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "productvariant " does not exist

Comment: `Product.hasMany(ProductVariant, { as: 'variant', foreignKey: 'product_id' })
ProductVariant.belongsTo(Product)`

Comment: I believe you can check the exact name of the table from the database and just change if there is minor tweak in there.